# Xamarin UI.Test - How can I Close my App after login and re - open to check Login Session is continued or not?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

As i need to check my Login Session is continued or not ?
I am using for Android Application.
Kindly help.

Comment: Hi Mahesh - Let me know if you need any more help! If my answer has resolved your question, please mark it as "Answered" to assist fellow developers who may have the same question in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force-close an app using UITest.

You also cannot send an Android app to the background using UITest.

You *can* send an iOS app to the Background via UITest using the `SendAppToBackground` method. Below is sample code that shows how to implement `SendAppToBackground`.

```
    internal static void SendAppToBackgroundAndConfigurePushNotifications(IApp app, int backgroundTimeInMilliseconds, bool takeScreenShotWhenBackgrounded = false, string screenShotString = "")
    {
        if (app is AndroidApp)
            return;

        ((iOSApp)app).SendAppToBackground(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(backgroundTimeInMilliseconds));

        if (takeScreenShotWhenBackgrounded)
            app.Screenshot(screenShotString);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh - Let me know if you need any more help! If this answer has resolved your question, please mark it as "Answered" to assist fellow developers who may have the same question in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can send an Android app to the background by using `app.Back()` repeatedly until you leave it.

Although, how to call it back? I do not know.